# Is there a well known design pattern to allow callbacks to be registered after the async call?

Tags: asynchronous, design-patterns, callback

When you make an async call you usually have to pass it a callback to process the result.

This is counter-intuitive to the one reading the code. We usually think about what to do and then about what to do later but in this cases we need to define what to do with the result before we define the action that is run first.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url1,
    success: function(data) {
        data1 = data;
        if(data2) perform();
    },
});
```

I have seen (and I implemented myself in java) other pattern where you make the async call first getting a token for the operation and then you register callbacks to it.

If the async operation has been run before the callback register then it (the callback) is called synchronously of it it hasn't been run it works as a normal callback like a subscription to the result then it is run.

Example (pseudocode):

```
ajax(url)
  .andThen({ successHandler code })
  .onError({ errorHandler code})
```

What is the name of this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

[Promises, Futures, or Deferreds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) are callback managers that are used to chain subsequent asynchronous code such that they avoid nested callbacks.

In JavaScript, promises have been formalized in [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/), but there are numerous implementations that may or may not follow the formal standard, such as jQuery's Deferreds pre version 3.